# Unable to set cookies with JMeter

Tags: php, cookies, jmeter

I am trying to perform a small load test on site I have developed. It requires user to login to application and then perform further actions.

Test I have created - 
[image]

Here as per the tutorials I have followed I have placed a cookie manager to store the cookies. Now the response header sent by doLogin.php - 
[image]

But this cookie PHPSESSID never sent back to server in the redirected request to home.php 
[image]

so home.php sees it as an unauthorized request and denies. So is there anything I am missing here?

Thanks

Comment: glad you sorted it out. we would have needed to see the defaults and cookie configs to work it out for you. check out the HTTP Authorization Manager and Login Config Element for alternative ways to perform the login and handle the session automatically.

Comment: Thanks Charlie will surely check out

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable/add the property `CookieManager.save.cookies=true` in the jmeter.properties file under /bin folder of JMeter installation path.

This enables the cookies from the first request to be stored under the current thread. [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager/) might explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

- Create a **Test Plan** with some name and some elements
  [image: test plan elements addition]
- **HTTP Request Defaults**
  [image: http request defaults]
- Empty **HTTP Cookie Manager**
  [image: http cookie manager]
- Login **HTTP Request** with credentials specified
  [image]
- Required **HTTP Request**
  [image]
- **View Results Tree** listener
  [image]

Testing:
During Login Page passing jmeter gets a Cookie:
[image]

During a real request, jmeter uses the Cookie which have been set during Login Page passing:
[image]

Also, make sure you have `CookieManager.save.cookies=true` in your jmeter `user.properties` file as Ronnie said.

```
$ cat ~/.local/share/jmeter/bin/user.properties | grep Cookie
CookieManager.save.cookies=true
```

After the file modification close and open jmeter again.

Answer (score -1):

You need add 1 more HTTP request to get login page with GET method. Then you can use your added login request with user name and password with POST method. Just add 1 more http request above your already added login request.

Comment: Sorry helping hands that didn't work actually, however I got it working :) Although its bit weird that I modified the httprequestdefaults, the server name I was entering was the path till that folder instead of putting only the server's name. Thanks Anyways :)

Comment: this answer doesn't explain the problem, or explain why this is an answer. doesn't really make much sense.